# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while decoding URL into Bitmap Android?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have created android application which has images which I am decoding from URL. I am getting following error while decoding URL into Bitmap. Its occurring on random phones. What is best case the error doesnt occur.

Following is error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:663)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:735)
```

This is code i used to decode image url:

```
  Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
String filePath = imageURL;
InputStream in = null;
in = new java.net.URL(filePath).openStream();
BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
o.inSampleSize = 8;
o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
o.inPurgeable = true;
mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
return mIcon11;
```

I don't want it to crash in any  case.

Please help

Comment: Before doing anything with bitmap you have to go through android's Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently section http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: Similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441644/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmapfactory-decodestrpath

Comment: @almasshaikh i have inserted that for recycling and released. Let see

Answer (score 0):

You can go with universial image loader liabrary.
It is having good handling for images also provide cache for them.
https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

You can use:-
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync(uri, targetImageSize, options);

Comment: I am using Picasso and I have provided option to set image as wallpaper where I need to decode URL into bitmap which is input to method.

Comment: I think Universal Image Loader have very good implementation for handling of bitmap try to solve problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Hi vo12 USE **Aquery (https://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading) or universal library(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** to manage the decoding the image or managing images these are best in my opinion i also faced similar issue i used these and now outofmemory error is rare.

Comment: I am using Picasso and I have provided option to set image as wallpaper where I need to decode URL into bitmap which is input to method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had fixed this type of error by reducing the WIDTH and HEIGHT of the image.It might be in your case too and error was same as yours "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError".carefully go through your all images u have used in your application, it might be some of images will have different width/height than others images.I think your will crash with some specific device,not with all android devices(because i my scenario,my app was not able to open with samsung s3,s4 note 2,xperia c etc,but all doing good). Actually its cause by images is not adjustable on to the device screen.

Comment: Hi images size are same. Actually I am setting wallpaper and it needa bitmap object as input so while decoding it fails