# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, google-apps

I get that error when I try running my app.  I saw other posts on this topic, but none of them were applicable to this code.  One solution that is not applicable here was changing the android:background property to a drawable.  That obviously is not true here.  Here is the activities code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/backg"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion.MainMenu">

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/lrplaybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:background="@drawable/lrhighscores"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="30dp" />


<Button
    android:background="@drawable/lrhelpbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="30dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Full error logs:

```
01-10 11:58:19.359    3091-3091/tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion/tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion.MainMenu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:353)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1930)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3336)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3273)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:421)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:184)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at tirg.com.kindust.bobda.tirginvasion.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:14)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove `android:background="@drawable/backg"` and see if the app still crashes?

Comment: can you please post your java classes as well.This seems to be a referencing issue

Comment: I need the background.  The java is nothing right now.  I am currently only designing its UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My picture was 5000x7000(TOO BIG!).  Fixed by resizing it!

Answer (score 0):

See the size of your background drawable `android:background="@drawable/backg"`. Try making the image dimensions (resolution) smaller (and/or smaller sized background image). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20680451/3879470).

As you can see this is causing it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:500)
        ......
```

You can also see [this](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/java-heap-space). You can also try to set the background from code, take help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20442153/3879470) using `inSampleSize` to load scales bitmaps to memory.

Comment: I want it to resize for all screen sizes.  How can I do that?

Comment: FIXED by resizing image

Comment: that is what i said make the image dimensions(resolution) smaller.