# App not working in avd

Tags: android, android-studio

If you can't help don't vote it in negative.. Please give other chance..... And this one is not repetitive I tried all the solution given before

The default activity_main.xml wasn't working . so I created another one as deleting the previous. But now when I start Avd it(app) closes with msg: "unfortunately app stopped working".

Everything seems Fine in graphical Layout .. It just The AVD I think

log Cat:

```
11-20 22:07:17.326 2381-2381/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
11-20 22:07:18.198 2381-2384/com.example.abhinav.vendue W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.062ms
11-20 22:07:19.330 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 9.928ms for cause Alloc
11-20 22:07:19.378 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2821(231KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 679KB/1117KB, paused 4.957ms total 39.087ms
11-20 22:07:19.418 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 163(19KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 60% free, 659KB/1683KB, paused 4.529ms total 35.334ms
11-20 22:07:19.425 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.134ms
11-20 22:07:19.486 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 15(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 3.219ms total 51.322ms
11-20 22:07:19.488 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 97MB allocation
11-20 22:07:19.637 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 36.059ms total 116.237ms
11-20 22:07:19.648 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 102400012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
11-20 22:07:19.667 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 18.213ms for cause Alloc
11-20 22:07:19.686 2381-2384/com.example.abhinav.vendue W/art: Suspending all threads took: 11.017ms
11-20 22:07:19.728 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5(608B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 4.534ms total 59.137ms
11-20 22:07:19.772 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 10(320B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 6.520ms total 39.893ms
11-20 22:07:19.822 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 7.644ms total 39.046ms
11-20 22:07:19.832 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 97MB allocation
11-20 22:07:19.870 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 647KB/1671KB, paused 3.137ms total 35.320ms
11-20 22:07:19.876 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 102400012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
11-20 22:07:19.876 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-20 22:07:19.883 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.abhinav.vendue, PID: 2381
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 102400012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:637)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:63)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:59)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:806)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:836)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.abhinav.vendue.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-20 22:07:19.885 2381-2381/com.example.abhinav.vendue E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
11-20 22:07:20.818 2381-2384/com.example.abhinav.vendue W/art: Suspending all threads took: 89.265ms
11-20 22:07:21.314 2381-2384/com.example.abhinav.vendue W/art: Suspending all threads took: 65.580ms
11-20 22:07:23.988 2381-2381/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2381 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Why did it stop? Help us out, we are not psychics

Comment: Provide a log of the stack trace with your question. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: @TimCastelijns Sorry, but I wasn't aware what you need

Comment: @MorrisonChang I've uploaded the Log Cat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OutOfMemoryError** is the most common problem occur in android while especially dealing with bitmaps. This error is thrown by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) when an object cannot be allocated due to lack of memory space and also, the garbage collector cannot free some space.

I think you should read some at Android's Developer page, specially here: [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Read all 5 lessons and rewrite your code again. If it still doesn't work we will be happy to see what you've done wrong with the tutorial material.

Here some of possible answers for these type of errors in SOF

[Android: BitmapFactory.decodeStream() out of memory with a 400KB file with 2MB free heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820266/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-out-of-memory-with-a-400kb-file-with-2mb-f)

[How to solve java.lang.OutOfMemoryError trouble in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android)

[Android : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558713/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441644/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmapfactory-decodestrpath)

[Solution for OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget](https://androidactivity.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/solution-for-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget/)