# How to reduce the bitmap image using the URL?

Tags: android, bitmap

I am using Mapbox in my application so I'm displaying customizing marker in the map.I will get image from API as image URL,if I directly pass the url image is not displying so I converted as the Bitmap image,sometimes applciation getting crashed.Please help me.

*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 53934348 byte allocation with 4194208 free bytes and 36MB until OOM*

Note:while converting the url into bitmap that time itself application crashed sometimes.

Code:

```
//converting the url into bitmap
try {
    URL url = new URL(“http://192.168.0.109/images/profile/2018-04-03-14-01-022017-11-13-07-12-36Image.jpg”);
 Bitmap   bitmapimage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()); }
catch(IOException e) { System.out.println(e); }

//customizing the marker

MarkerViewOptions markerViewOptions = new MarkerViewOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(userDetails.getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(userDetails.getLongitutde())))
          .icon(drawableToIcon(getContext(),bitmapimage, userDetails.getUser_status()));

mMapBoxMap.addMarker(markerViewOptions);


//method to customise the layout

public Icon drawableToIcon(@NonNull Context context, Bitmap image, String status) {

        View marker = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_layout, null);


   CircleImageView markerImage = (CircleImageView) marker.findViewById(R.id.user_dp);
   markerImage.setImageBitmap(image);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        marker.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(52, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        marker.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        marker.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        marker.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(marker.getMeasuredWidth(), marker.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        marker.draw(canvas);

        return IconFactory.getInstance(context).fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

I referred this link *http://madhusudhanrc.blogspot.in/2012/09/reduce-bitmap-size-using.html* ,if I shrink the image means its not diplaying.Please help me to reduce the bitmap size.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20441644/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmapfactory-decodestrpath

Comment: `I referred this link` there are no links in the question.

Comment: android:largeHeap="true" add in application tag in manifest

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719620/how-to-solve-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-trouble-in-android

Comment: @quicklearner, it is a workaround, not a solution. He is trying to load 53 MB bitmaps. Large heap can work until he gets as large image as it will be large even for large heap.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: `android:largeHeap="true"` never a solution .With this You are just manipulating the chances of error.  See [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html). Use small size compressed images.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Comment: i added android:largeHeap="true" eventhough it will happen.i referred the above link  BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inSampleSize = 8;
 mBitmapInsurance = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath,options);,but in decodefile i cant able to pass the imageurl

Comment: anyone give proper answer please